# Need help to call a function which sets a avalue before inserting into a table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a function which returns a score as int

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[CalculateScore]
   (@gender CHAR(1), @name varchar(20), @dob datetime, 
   @weight int, @height int, @smoker BIT, @Earning int)   
RETURNS INT
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @Score INT


DECLARE @Age INT
SELECT @Age = DATEDIFF(YEAR, @dob, GETDATE())

SELECT 
    @Score = CASE 
                WHEN @Age BETWEEN 20 AND 30 THEN 5
                WHEN @Age BETWEEN 31 AND 40 THEN 4
                WHEN @Age BETWEEN 41 AND 50 THEN 3
                WHEN @Age > 50 THEN 2
                ELSE 0
            END


DECLARE @WeightHeight INT

SET @WeightHeight = @Weight / @height

SET 
   @Score = @Score + 
            CASE 

              WHEN @WeightHeight BETWEEN 20 AND 25 THEN 1
              WHEN @WeightHeight BETWEEN 25 AND 30 THEN 3
              WHEN @WeightHeight BETWEEN 30 AND 35 THEN 5
              WHEN @WeightHeight BETWEEN 35 AND 40 THEN 2
              ELSE 0  
            END


IF @Smoker = 0
    SET @Score = @Score + 5


SET 
   @Score = @Score + 
            CASE 
               WHEN @Earning < 50000 THEN 1
               WHEN @Earning BETWEEN 50001 AND 60000 THEN 2
               WHEN @Earning BETWEEN 60001 AND 70000 THEN 3
               WHEN @Earning > 70000 THEN 4
            END


RETURN @Score
END
```

I would like to be able to run an INSERT code like

```
INSERT INTO Table
(Gender, Name, dob, Weight, Height, Smoker, Earning)
VALUES 
(1, 'James', '19841230', 59, 185, 0, 80000), 
(1, 'Jack', '19700430', 75, 182, 1, 95000),
(1, 'James', '19670721', 60, 167, 0, 75000); 
GO
```

Rather than something like

```
INSERT INTO Table(Gender, Name, dob, Weight, Height, Smoker, Earning, memberID, CalculatedScore)
SELECT
@Gender, @Name, @dob, @Weight, @Height, @Smoker, @Earning
dbo.CalculateScore(@Gender, @Name, @dob, @Weight, @Height, @Smoker, @Earning)
```

Which would insert these values into the table but ALSO automatically add the calculated score from the function and a unique Primary Key into the columns 'CalculatedScore' and'Member_ID' which are also in the table.

I figure i am supposed the call the function before the insert and store the returned value but i cannot figure out how.

Any help would be appreciated!

Cheers

Comment: Hi, is this sorted now?

Comment: Is there any chance that the way to calculate the score will change in the future? If so, do you a) Need to know which version was used to compute the stored value, or b) Need to update all existing rows using the new function. If it's b) do you really need to *store* this value rather than just obtain it when reading from the table?

Comment: This is assuming these calculations will not change :) Obtaining it whilst reading from the table seems like a good idea, i'm at a loss as to how though..

Comment: Since it's based on age, the value would/could change over time. Also, are you sure your age calculation is correct? `DATEDIFF(year,'20121231','20130101')` returns 1 even though most people wouldn't consider a 1 day old to be a year old.

Answer (score 3):

Could you add a calculated column?

```
ALTER TABLE Member ADD CalculatedScore AS 
  dbo.CalculateScore(Gender, Name, dob, Weight, Height, Smoker, Earning);
```

You won't be able to index this column though because it is not deterministic. That is to say a score could change with no actual change to the data (i.e. because they have got one year older), so you can't even maintain this accurately with triggers. If you wanted a peristed column that can be indexed the only way would be to run a nightly job that updates a static column.

**[Example on SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/51e1e/1)**

Comment: hi thanks alot this is very helpful and seems to be working perfectly except for i'm getting an incorrect syntax on a comma on line 7 of the sql fiddle and i cannot figure out why, hah.

Comment: Line 7 of the SqlFiddle only says `AS`, there is no comma. Have you made any changes to the fiddle?

Comment: I have put my code in the fiddle and everything works fine, yet when i put into sql server i get that error. Do you have any idea what the issue could be? I'm quite confused.

Comment: Even if i add more code beforehand, it still says the issue is on line 8

Comment: I have no idea why it would be working on SQL-Fiddle and not on your server. Try doing each bit separately, i.e. create the table, create the function, then add the calculated column.

Comment: everything works accept the insert values, where it comes up with the comma error again even though (i'm very sure) there is nothing out of place. I'll keep reading it guess.

Comment: ahh on startup it says sql server 2008, but SELECT @@VERSION returns 2005.

Answer (score 1):

A little simplified your function -

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[CalculateScore] 
(
      @dob DATETIME
    , @weight INT
    , @height INT
    , @smoker BIT
    , @Earning INT
)
RETURNS INT
AS BEGIN

    DECLARE @Score INT

    SELECT @Score =
        CASE
            WHEN Age BETWEEN 20 AND 30 THEN 5
            WHEN Age BETWEEN 31 AND 40 THEN 4
            WHEN Age BETWEEN 41 AND 50 THEN 3
            WHEN Age > 50 THEN 2 
            ELSE 0
        END +
        CASE
            WHEN WeightHeight BETWEEN 20 AND 25 THEN 1
            WHEN WeightHeight BETWEEN 25 AND 30 THEN 3
            WHEN WeightHeight BETWEEN 30 AND 35 THEN 5
            WHEN WeightHeight BETWEEN 35 AND 40 THEN 2 
            ELSE 0
        END +
        CASE
            WHEN @Smoker = 0 THEN 5 ELSE 0
        END +
        CASE
            WHEN @Earning < 50000 THEN 1
            WHEN @Earning BETWEEN 50001 AND 60000 THEN 2
            WHEN @Earning BETWEEN 60001 AND 70000 THEN 3
            WHEN @Earning > 70000 THEN 4
            ELSE 0
        END
    FROM
    (
        SELECT  Age = DATEDIFF(YEAR, @dob, GETDATE())
            ,   WeightHeight = CAST(@Weight / @height AS INT)
    ) t

    RETURN @Score

END
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try using triggers, which can can be invoked before insert